# Locking ConcurrentHashMap for an exclusive read

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, concurrenthashmap

I have several threads that save information to my `ConcurrentHashMap<K,V>`. I'm supposed to take a snapshot of the whole Map in a parent thread, process the information in it and eventually empty it from all values and keys.

How can I make sure that during the read (in the parent thread), it is not gonna be updated by any child-threads writing to it until I'm done with it? Is it possible to lock this data structure with a semaphore or a mutex?

Comment: You can simply use a monitor and `synchronize` over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. Using a monitor to guard the map `field` so when you're taking the snapshot no one else can put values inside it.

```java
public class Example<K, V> {
    private final Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
    private final Object monitor = new Object();

    public Object snapshot() {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            // take the snapshot and return it
        }
    }

    public V put(K key, V value) {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            return map.put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Also in this example you can simplify it by using a simple `HashMap` instead of a `ConcurrentHashMap` because you have the monitor guarding accesses to that field.

Comment: What's then the point of using a ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: Exactly, I just used it since the question author was using it. But in this case you can simplify it by using a `HashMap`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I used ConcurrentHashMap cause I thought that it was needed for multiple threads to share it and save data safely. When I'm taking a snapshot from from it, I wanted to make sure that none of them can access it a the time of processing the data.

Comment: It would work if the `entrySet` returned by the map didn't reflect any other updates but it does like the docs say [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#entrySet--).

Comment: @chriptus13 that’s not a special property of the `entrySet()`. It’s the general property of `ConcurrentHashMap` not to support locking of the entire map.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`ReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html).

This gives you a pair of locks:

- A read lock, which many threads can acquire at the same time
- A write lock, which only one thread can hold, and whilst held no thread can hold the read lock.

Despite the names, there is no reason these locks have to be used for reading and writing specifically:

- Acquire (and release) the read lock for threads that are updating the map
- Acquire (and release) the write lock for the thread which has to see the whole map at once.